# Javascript network error occurs when trying to return .txt from server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got an empty div (`id="theDiv"`) in my .html that I'm trying to fill with the content of a text file. It looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Practice.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <p>Connected to server.</p>
    <div id="theDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to print out when each readyState occurs in the process. The javascript looks good to me but when I run the page I get an alert with "NetworkError: A network error occurred." which I assume is probably triggered by the first alert in the script. I have used a linter and still have no idea where in the .js the problem is so I'll put everything here:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

return xmlHttp;
}

function process() {
    if(xmlHttp) {
      try{
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "Practice.txt", true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
      }catch(e) {
        alert( e.toString() );
      }
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
    theDiv = document.getElementById("theDiv");
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==1) {
        theDiv.innerHTML += "Status 1: server connection established <br/>";
    }else if(xmlHttp.readyState==2) {
        theDiv.innerHTML += "Status 2: request received <br/>";
    }else if(xmlHttp.readyState==3) {
        theDiv.innerHTML += "Status 3: processing request <br/>";
    }else if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {

        if(xmlHttp.status==200) {
          try{
            text = xmlHttp.responseText;
            theDiv.innerHTML += "Status 4: request is finished and response is ready <br/>";
            theDiv.innerHTML += text;
          }catch(e){
            alert( e.toString() );
        }
        }else{
            alert( xmlHttp.statusText );
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long code. I'm really quite befuddled so I would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: Request should be received by a script which returns headers, in case of `txt`-file no headers are sent, so it's a network error.

Comment: You checked if you can get file "Practice.txt" by standart request?

Answer (score 2):

I just copied your source code and ran it all on my own server.  There were absolutely no issues with it.  I made my own "Practice.txt" file, as well.  No problems.

I put the script at the end of the `body`, and wrapped `process()` in the closure, which worked; I also took away the closure from `process()`, and put `process()` inline as an `onload` handler to the `body` tag, just like you did.  Once again, no issues.

So, here are some potential causes of your problems:

1. Is "Practice.txt" in the same directory as your doc that is requesting it?
2. Is there some configuration in your server somewhere that won't allow you to request that specific resource?
3. Is, for some strange reason, the fact that your script is external and in the `head` causing some weird issue?
4. Have you tried requesting any other resource besides "Practice.txt"? Is so, what were the results?
5. And lastly... is your server on?  Gotta throw that one in there (I assume the server is on, but who knows.)